# how to call url dynamically in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a function like this:

```
function contentDisp()
{
$.ajax({
url : "../Patient/brest/ros_brest.php",
success : function (data) {
$("#dynamicContent").html(data);
}
});
}
```

i have a menu like this:

```
<div  id="leftmenu">
<ul id="accordion">
    <li><div>BREAST</div>
        <ul>
            <li ><a href="#" onClick="contentDisp();">BREAST</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

When end user clicks on menu item the concerned page to be display in the div alloted for that . Everything is working fine but now if i want to do the same for all menu items then how i have to do with this: url : "../Patient/brest/ros_brest.php", instead of the url statically how i have to pass it dynamically.

Thank you in advance
ramsai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function contentDisp(url)
{
$.ajax({
url : url,
success : function (data) {
$("#dynamicContent").html(data);
}
});
}

<li ><a href="#" onClick="contentDisp("../Patient/brest/ros_brest.php");">BREAST</a></li>
```

However, What I would suggest is you remove the onClick handlers and put the url as the href 
that way with js off users still get somethign (read about progressive enhancement to learn more) like so

```
$("#accordion>a").click(function()
{
$.ajax({
url : $(this).attr("href"),
success : function (data) {
$("#dynamicContent").html(data);
}
});
 return false;
});
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/ixifah/4

Comment: i did wht you said in last post when i click the menu item it is opening in new page  and it is not calling the function $(#accordion>a) anything i have to add thank you in advance

Comment: $document.ready(function(){
$("#accordion>a").click(function()
{
$.ajax({
url : $(this).attr("href"),
success : function (data) {
$("#dynamicContent").html(data);
}
});
 return false;
});
});

Answer (score 3):

Something like that:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a.dyn-load").on("click", function() {
      $("#" + $(this).attr("data-target")).load($(this).attr("href"));
      return false;
   });
});
</script>

<a href="/some/url" class="dyn-load" data-target="dyn-content">bleh</a>
<a href="/some/url2" class="dyn-load" data-target="dyn-content">bleh2</a>
<div id="dyn-content"></div>
<a href="/some/url3" class="dyn-load" data-target="dyn-content2">bleh3</a>
<a href="/some/url4" class="dyn-load" data-target="dyn-content2">bleh4</a>
<div id="dyn-content2"></div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/RnMJN/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
<a href="some_page_url" onClick="contentDisp(this);">BREAST</a>

function contentDisp(obj) {
  var someurl = $(obj).attr("href");
  $.ajax({
        url : someurl,
        success : function (data) {
            $("#dynamicContent").html(data);
        }
  });
}
```